# CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND not defined

Tags: cmake

I am using cmake 3.0.2 (on debian 8). I am trying to add some tests using a custom `check` target like this:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(check
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1 ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND}
  DEPENDS test_1 test_2)
```

I am using the built-in [CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND.html) which is supposedly available in cmake However, the variable is undefined and the command does not work. My questions are the following:

1: Am I doing it wrong? It seems to work with cmake 3.3.2, when was this variable added?

2: How can I get this to work in cmake 3.0.2, should I just replace CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND with "ctest"?

Comment: You are pointing to CMake 3.0's documentation which describes the existence of the variable. To double check, you can add `message("ctest should be: ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND}")` right in front of your command. What is the error message you get?

Comment: Well, I just get the empty string

Comment: That's weird. I just tested with CMake 2.8.6 and it worked for me. I suppose it's either a Debian bug or a corrupted installation. Do you mind re-installing cmake?